# authentication error 403 firebase on ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-oauth, google-authentication

I want to use firebase auth with google inside a ReactJS web app on and when created an app and hooked up everything(localhost) based on firebase documentation I got this error:

p.s: I enabled the sign-in method `google` and `email/password`. Also `localhost` is there in the "authorized domains" section.

How can I solve this issue?

[image]

and here's config code:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'API KEY',
  authDomain: 'crwn-test.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://crwn-test.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'crwn-test',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: 'MESSAGE ID',
  appId: '1:727447670851:web:30c8f3e12fca101f'
};

app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = app.auth();
export const firestore = app.firestore();

const provider = new app.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');
provider.setCustomParameters({ prompt: 'select_account' });
export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

export default app;
```

Comment: Please hide your client id as it is sensitive information, if possible give more info about how you are configuring are you using any component for google authentication because there are plenty of them available.

Comment: and as per the message please check your google cloud console wheather it is configured or not

Comment: @techipank thank you for heads up. I added the config code and how I setup auth.

Comment: Please note that your client id is still visible in the revision history. And when something is on the internet it's practicly impossible to completely remove it.

Comment: @AndréKool it's a test project, i dont care about it that much. I'm here to find a solution.

Comment: Have you checked google clound console wheather you project is added or not

Comment: @techipank yup, it's there and doesn't work.